# Google App Engine - random ssl connection resets

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a servlet hosted within Google App Engine. As part of the business logic, it performs a HTTPS request to another webservice. I started getting SSL connection reset exceptions but they appear to be happening in a random fashion. I haven't been able to repeat the exception and they start happening even more over time but then can fade away and come back. I've performed stress testing on the remote service directly from other machines and never receive a single issue. The only way I've been able to deal with this is by redeploying the application but it can take a few redeployments before the issue goes away. I am confident it isnt an issue with the remote service but something happening within Google App Engine.

Comment: Showing a code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Hello, could you also include the logs related to the issue on top of a code snippet where the API calls to the other web service are made? The logs can be found in GCP under Stackdriver Logging.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your comments, we just got to the bottom of this yesterday. It was a dynamic application being deployed, so the instances should be managing their resources by themselves. However, what was happening is that an instance was running low on memory which resulted in SSL connection resets. This is why they were appearing in a random manner and degrading even worse overtime. The way this was resolved was to upgrade the resources, changing the deployment configuration to use an F2 instance rather than the default F1 instance. Since doing so there hasn't been a connection dropped. Thanks again for your responses and I hope this helps anyone who may experience something similar.

Comment: No worries, thanks for sharing the workaround with us.